# i need to make multiselect as selected and shown values athe time of edit

Tags: javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://phpcoder.tech/multiselect/css/jquery.multiselect.css">
```

this is the link of mulitiselect

```
 $("#Nationality").multiselect("clearSelection");

        $("#Nationality").multiselect('refresh');
       
        var myarray = nationalties.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
            console.log(myarray)
            console.log(myarray[i])
            //"[value='" + val + "']"
            $('#Nationality').find('option[value="' + myarray[i] + '"').attr("selected", "selected");
           // $(this).find("[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled", true);
         // $('#Nationality').find('option[value="RS"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        }
        $('#Nationality').multiselect({
            columns: 1,
            placeholder: 'Select Nationality',
            search: true,
            selectAll: true
        });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the array of selected items as follows, and it will work fine:
`$('#Nationality').multipleSelect('setSelects', myarray);`